# User name not found or incorrect password error message too vague

Tags: security, authentication

In many applications when you make a mistake in either your user name or password you get a non-specific error indicating that either the user name entered does not exist or the password is incorrect for that user name.

I (naively) would expect the application to specify *which* one of the two errors happened.  Is there any reason for not differentiating between them?  I guess it would make it more difficult for an attacker to guess a correct user name/password combination, but is there any literature, research or similar that backs up this assumption?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason would be security: it prevents [finding out which user names exist](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/username-enumeration-vulnerabilities/) based on failed attempts.

This should be balanced with the user experience; if you're told that *either* your user name or password is incorrect, it can be perceived as very unhelpful or annoying.

Comment: But the information about which user names exist can often be obtained by creating new accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Common sense dictates that an ambiguous message is better because an attacker would be unable to know if they had guesses a correct username.

Answer (score 2):

It's an extra hoop the attacker needs to jump through. If he's cold-attacking an application he won't know any usernames or passwords. Why give him an extra bit of information to tell him that he has found a username? It's better to withhold the information.

What if the attacker is just looking to confirm that a particular username exists? Say, the name of a politician as a username for a fetish site, as an example. The username itself is sensitive information and you do not want to confirm which exist and which do not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s exactly why many apps/sites do not specify which part of the login is bad. I used to have the same complaint, but then I read a bunch of computer security books including *[19 Deadly Sins of Software Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072260858)*. Among other things like overflows and SQL injection, Michael Howard does explain the reasoning of returning a unified error for logins.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

it's all about giving an attacker as little information as possible.
Some sites go even further with this on password reminders. When you input your email address to receive a new password or a password reset link they don't tell you if your email address is registered in the database but give you a message like this: "if the email address you entered is in our database you will receive a message..." This prevents the attacker from finding out which email address was used by the victim and may also announce the victim that someone is trying to break into her account.